# Can't parse the whole html page for some reason using jsoup

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jsoup

I'm trying to get the whole body page from youtube.com but only get a quarter of it for weird reasons
can somebody help me out here?

heres the code:

```
private static String data;

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
   try {
       Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Mettalica").get();
       
       data = doc.body().html();
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
   //basically sysout the html results of the youtube search
   super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

   Log.d(TAG, data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Doc Object has full HTML as well, you need to dig deeper to look for a better way but `doc.outerHtml()` should do the Job for you. Below SS also illustrates this object's state in Debug mode To compare with [View Source of URL](http://view-source:https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Mettalica)

[image: Debug mode screenshot of doc Object]